# JUnit lambda expression

Tags: java, testing, lambda, junit

Good morning,
I need to make a test for a class which use the following method:

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.startsWith("FILE_500"+date));
```

To test this part of code I have the following code:

```
when(directory.listFiles((dir,name)->name.startsWith("FILE_500"))).thenReturn(files);
```

But IDE says "Unnecessary stubbings detected" because name.startsWith is never call on test.

How can I test this part of code?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to test the behavior of the listFiles method when it is passed a lambda expression as a parameter, you can create a mock object of the File class and set it up to return the expected array of files when the listFiles method is called with a lambda expression that matches the condition you want to test.

Please refer to the example test case using Mockito :

```
@Test
    public void testListFiles() {
        File[] expectedFiles = {new File("FILE_50020230215.txt"), new File("FILE_50020230215.csv")};
        File directory = mock(File.class);
        when(directory.listFiles(any())).thenReturn(expectedFiles);
        
        File[] actualFiles = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.startsWith("FILE_50020230215"));
        
        assertEquals(expectedFiles.length, actualFiles.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < expectedFiles.length; i++) {
            assertEquals(expectedFiles[i], actualFiles[i]);
        }
    }
```